# Call jquery in a subcontext again in jquery command chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
jQuery(selector).jQuery(subselector).command(....)
```

My code is like this:

```
$(' .species')
.filter(function () { return !$(this).data('hidden_code_ready'); }
.wrapInner('<span class="species_info" />')
.append('<a href="" class="show_species"></a>')
.data('hidden_code_ready', true)
```

Now for each of these matched elements (.species) I want to install click handler to the .show_species. I know I can probably do something like:

```
$('.show_species',
    $(' .species')
    .filter(function () { return !$(this).data('hidden_code_ready'); }
    .wrapInner('<span class="species_info" />')
    .append('<a href="" class="show_species"></a>')
    .data('hidden_code_ready', true)
).click(...);
```

but this is really awkward. Is there any possibility to do something like:

```
$(' .species')
.filter(function () { return !$(this).data('hidden_code_ready'); }
.wrapInner('<span class="species_info" />')
.append('<a href="" class="show_species"></a>')
.data('hidden_code_ready', true)
.jQuery('.show_species').click(....);
```

???

Preferably working in jQuery 1.3.2 too. Thanks!

Comment: Use .find?

e.g. $('.species').find('.subspecies')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close! The function is called [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find), not `jQuery`:

```
$('.species')
    .filter(function () { return !$(this).data('hidden_code_ready'); }
    .wrapInner('<span class="species_info" />')
    .append('<a href="" class="show_species"></a>')
    .data('hidden_code_ready', true)
    .find('.show_species').click(....);
```

Comment: great! Thank you! I knew there must be some simple solution for this :-)